# Clear output cache by MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "startindex;endindex")]
public ActionResult GetTop100Student(int startindex, int endindex)
{
    artistlist = new List<Artist>();          
    artistlist = statisticsmanager.GetTopStudent(id,  startindex, endindex);   

    ViewData["studentlist"] = studentlist; 
    return view();
}
```

I call the function by jquery/json.

XHR finished loading: "http://EEE.COM/Top100/GetTop100Student/?startindex=1&endindex=10". jquery-1.4.4.min.js:145

XHR finished loading: "http://EEE.COM/Top100/GetTop100Student/?startindex=11&endindex=20". jquery-1.4.4.min.js:145

XHR finished loading: "http://EEE.COM/Top100/GetTop100Student/?startindex=21&endindex=30". jquery-1.4.4.min.js:145

XHR finished loading: "http://EEE.COM/Top100/GetTop100Student/?startindex=31&endindex=40". jquery-1.4.4.min.js:145

XHR finished loading: "http://EEE.COM/Top100/GetTop100Student/?startindex=41&endindex=50". jquery-1.4.4.min.js:145

I make every call in output cache. My question is: How can I remove this output cache. Please anyone solve this kind of solution. Thanks advance

Answer (score 1):

See ServerFault:

https://serverfault.com/questions/176943/will-an-iis-reset-force-cached-items-to-be-resent

It looks like IISReset will do it, else try cycling the Application Pool for the site.